# How to get Android Context from Appium

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

Is there a way to retrieve the Android application `Context` in an Appium project? (Sorry if this is a trivial question, I am very new to Appium)

I found [this page](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/get-context/), however, this is not what I am looking for, what I am looking for it's rather an instance of  `android.content.Context`, that later I can use to access Android related components. Specifically, in my Appium tests I am trying to get an instance of `SharedPreferences` (which requires `Context`), so I can change some of the preferences before starting the tests.